# how to remove subview from app delegate?

Tags: iphone

i have one function in app delegate
the function has code in **appdelegate.m**

```
        OthersController *mm_OthersController = [[OthersController alloc] init];


        [mm_OthersController toggle_OF: mm_OthersController];
         [mm_OthersController release];
```

the toggle_OF function is in **OthersController.m** file which has been set in IB for tab bar item...

```
-(void)toggle_OF:(OthersController *)con
 {

[con.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
}
```

the break point goes perfectly...**but tool bar cannot be removed**......this function is called perfectly if i call within the **OthersController.m**

Comment: Why are you doing self = con; ? Why not go straight to [con.toolbar removeFromSuperview] ?

Comment: pls see my q again.....i did you told.?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things first and check if it then works;

```
OthersController *mm_OthersController = [[OthersController alloc] init];

[mm_OthersController toggle_OF];
[mm_OthersController release];
```

You don't have to give the parameter if using the function from inside the controller

```
-(void)toggle_OF
{
    [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Probably will not solve your entire problem, but makes the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: put breakpoint into your toggle_OF method and check if self.toolbar is not nil.